# Is there any risk in joining a minecraft public server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have recently restarted playing minecraft; I googled around a bit and I found many websites which offer the server address for public servers. Is there any security risk to me joining one of these servers? If so, how can I minimize this risk?

Comment: The risk would be someone else obtaining your IP.  Only play on reputable servers.  The risk is minimal.

Comment: I would also be very careful about what information I shared with people while connected to a public server.  An admin on a public server might start demanding things like your password or email "for game reasons," but in reality he may just be fishing for information he can use to hack you elsewhere on the internet.  Be prepared to leave a given server rather than give away information about yourself that might cause trouble far and wide.

Comment: Many servers offer a chat feature, if you do decide to participate in the chat, be very careful about what you share with people. Never share sensitive information, such as passwords. As mentioned before, only play on reputable servers, such as Hive, Hypixel and Mineplex.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to play only on servers you can trust, which are mostly the big and famous ones.
You can find a list of them [here](https://minecraftservers.org/).

As said in the comments though, and as always on the internet, be wary of what you share with others, avoid at all costs sharing your password, IP address and such with anyone you don't know and trust.

Answer (score 0):

The major issue is as the comments have mentioned: Someone else has your IP.

You don't necessarily need to tell your IP in the chat for others to know. All Minecraft server know what IP you are using to connect to it. You are basically disclosing your IP to people who have access to the "insides" of the server, or commands like `/dupeip` from LiteBans whenever you join a server, though most restrict IP access to the administration or staff team.

Note that servers with GeoIP enabled (from plugins) can also disclose your rough location through a simple command.